# The Crash after event finished in PySide6

Tags: crash, pyside6, python-3.11

I am new to PySide6 and I'm trying to code a two Widgets swap animation.

I also use a list to hold the pointers to the widgets for further usage.

My code works fine when moving widget down.

But when moving up, the program may crash after the swap is finished or swap wrong widgets.
When crashed,Terminal showed nothing.The program was just either freezed or shut down.
Here's my code.

```
def widgets_swap(self,widget1,mode:int):

    index1 = self.scripts.index(widget1)
    #move up
    if mode == 0 and index1 > 0:
        index2 = index1 - 1
        widget2 = self.scripts[index2]
    #move down
    elif mode == 1 and index1 < len(self.scripts) -1:
        index2 = index1 + 1
        widget2 = self.scripts[index2]
    
    else:
        print("Not moving")
        return
    
    #animation
    ani1 = QPropertyAnimation(widget1,b"pos")
    ani2 = QPropertyAnimation(widget2,b"pos")

    ani1.setDuration(50)
    ani1.setStartValue(widget1.pos())
    ani1.setEndValue(widget2.pos())
    ani2.setDuration(50)
    ani2.setStartValue(widget2.pos())
    ani2.setEndValue(widget1.pos())

    
    loop = QEventLoop()
    ani1.start()
    ani2.start()
    ani2.finished.connect(loop.quit)
    loop.exec()

    self.scripts[index1], self.scripts[index2] = self.scripts[index2], self.scripts[index1]

    self.ui.verticalLayout_6.removeWidget(widget1)
    self.ui.verticalLayout_6.removeWidget(widget2)
    self.ui.verticalLayout_6.insertWidget(index1,widget2,alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    self.ui.verticalLayout_6.insertWidget(index2,widget1,alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
```

The reason why the program crashed and how to fix it.

Comment: I found out that it was a Pyside6's bug. It works fine inPyside2.

Comment: About the wrong swap. It was my mistake to remove and insert 2 widgets in the same time.